# What is the best way in Xamarin Forms (Android) to check if mobile internet is turned on?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

As the headline says I am looking for a way to check if a device has its mobile data turned on. A tip or link would be helpful Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin.Essentials to check the internet connection.

Docs: [Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android)

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
{
    //Connection Available
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just comment on the 1st answer but my reputation is not enough so I am writing here.
The question of the post still remains when you are connected to a wifi network without internet connection (a smart appliance for example) and you have the mobile data connection enabled as well. In my case on android 7.1.1 the check for connection profiles returns only the WiFi. It returns Cellular only if I have mobile data connection enabled and wifi disabled. So is there a way to check if mobile data connection is just enabled even when the wifi is already connected?